# OpenGL doesn't draw (3.3+)

Tags: opengl

**Brief:**
I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/) about OpenGL for 2 days, and I still can't have a triangle drawn, so I'm asking for help here. The tutorial is turned to *OpenGL version 3.3* programing, using vertex arrays, buffers, etc. The libraries are: *GLFW3* and *GLEW*, and I setted them by myself. The screen keeps black all the time.

**Full code:**

[link here](http://pastebin.com/uUbzsnQ1)
(It's just like a Hello World opengl program)

**Further Details:**

- I get no errors at all.
- I downloaded a software to test my video card, and it supports *OpenGL 4.1+*
- Standard OpenGL code for drawing (from earlier version) such as [this one](http://pastebin.com/sQKx4C8q) works normally.
- I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
- I presume all the OpenGL implementation was dune right: I added *Additional Dependences*  to the linker as *glew32.lib*, *opengl32.lib*, *glfw3.lib*. The glew.dll was placed at SysWOW64 - because I'm running window 64bits, and glew is 32.

**Notes:** I've been working hard to find out what this is, but I can't find. I would appreciate if anyone could test [this code](http://pastebin.com/uUbzsnQ1) for me, so I can know if I implemented something wrong, and that its not my code.

Comment: Could you use glGetVersion or whatever it actually is once you create your context? The context profile could be different to the maximum supported one on your graphics card, depending on what you/glew have called.

Comment: I did: "GLdouble d =0; glGetDoublev(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &d);" and the value of d was 3.00000. Edit: I did again, using "glGetDoublev(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &d);" and the value of d was 3 again, that means I'm running 3.3

Comment: Hmm, it seems odd. That said, I always have issues with OpenGL 3+, but that's irrelevant. Have you added shaders?

Comment: I'm sure I didn't... and its really bugging me. >.<

Comment: I think this site is not about "here's my code, fix it". As far as I know, it's about asking specific questions to get specific answers. Maybe you could try narrowing your question much more.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that shaders are mandatory for newer versions of OpenGL, even if it's merely a flat shader.

Comment: @PandaPajama This isn't really a code dump - he's told us the problem, given what context and details he can, and has tried solving it himself (the 'Notes' subsection). That said, _what_ he has already tried would be nice.

Comment: @Polar By the corse of the tutorial, it should render a triangle already, but I will try what you said anyways.

Comment: @Polar: I've read the question three times, and I still only get "I'm doing this tutorial, code doesn't work, download here, please fix". The "further details" section makes it clear that the OP doesn't even know if it is a driver, code, IDE or dependency error. The "notes" section adds nothing to help me understand his problem (anybody can write "I've tried hard"), and all around I don't think it is an appropriate question for this site, in its current form. Maybe the OP could try narrowing his question?

Comment: If a question requires this much discussion, it's probably not a good question for the site. As Panda says, you may want to narrow the scope with further research. Take it to chat if you want to discuss it further.

Comment: @Polar Regarding your suggestion on using shaders, I tried to load one from the examples of the tutorial, and it kinda worked. (the shader didn't load, but the background was blue, and the space where the triangle should be was black, meaning something was actually rendered). I guess that was the problem, and its quite weird that I've never seen anywhere OpenGL 3.3+ requires this feature. Anyway, thanks a lot, I appreciate your endeavour to help ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I discovered the solution based on [Polar's](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/26929/polar) argument, I will just answer my own question.

As he said:

> I'm pretty certain that shaders are mandatory for newer versions of
>   OpenGL, even if it's merely a flat shader.

Just drawing points from a buffer, calling the method

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,3);
```

for instance, won't necessarily draw something (on new versions of OpenGL). It requires shaders. To make sure that something was being rendered, and that the black screen wasn't an uncompatibility problem, I called the method

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
```

before entering the main loop. Instead of a black window, here is the [result](http://i.minus.com/jbptB9jnUENehg.PNG). Problem solved.